# Wordpress - Automatic Background Updates

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added this code to my wp-config.php file in order to auto update core, themes, plugins and to turn off the email update notifications.

I am using the exact same settings sucessfully for my two other wordpress sites on the same hosting. The file/directory permissions seems to be the same etc.

For some unknown reason, this does not work on this current wordpress site, how can I troubleshot this auto update settings?

```
/* Auto Update Wordpress Core */
add_filter( 'auto_update_core', '__return_true' );

/* Disable email update notifications */
add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );

/* Auto Update Theme */
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true' );

/* Auto Update Plugins */
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
```

Comment: Where did you learn that adding filters in wp-config was good?? https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Read again, it says **not to do it**

Answer (score 0):

**step1:** Login to your cPanel

**step2:** Open the File Manager and then go to the WordPress installation files. You will need to find your wp-config.php file.

**step3:** Search for define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );

**step4:** Once you find the line, delete it from the WP-CONFIG.PHP file

**step5:** Click on SAVE in order to save your changes.

Comment: define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true ); It's not there